# dojo chart - Legend and Tooltip are displaying without style/theme

Tags: javascript, charts, dojo

I've just created a simple Chart2d, everything is ok about this chart (data-series are just displayed fine, the theme is ok and etc.) , So I just moved on and tried to add Tooltip and Legend features to this chart. So I come up with below code:

```
require([
"dojox/charting/Chart",
"dojox/charting/action2d/Tooltip",
"dojox/charting/themes/Tom",
"dojox/charting/widget/SelectableLegend",
"dojox/charting/plot2d/Lines",
"dojox/charting/plot2d/Markers",
"dojox/charting/axis2d/Default",
"dojo/store/JsonRest",
"dojo/store/Memory",
"dojo/store/Cache",
"dojox/charting/StoreSeries",
"dojo/domReady!"
], function(Chart, Tooltip, Tom, SelectableLegend, LinesPlot, JsonRest, StoreSeries){

// ... the data store is initialed here ..

chart.setTheme(Tom);

chart.addPlot("default", {
type: LinesPlot,
markers: true
});

.
.
.

chart.render();
var tip = new Tooltip(chart, "default");
var leg = new dojox.charting.widget.SelectableLegend({ chart: chart, horizontal: true }, "legend1");
});
```

Now, The problem is that I can see both Legend/Tooltip for this chart, but it seems that the chart theme is not applied for them.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My bad .. I just forgot to add main dojo stylesheet (+ optionally a theme) to my html document:

```
<style type="text/css">
@import "./res/dojo__1_10_4/dojo/resources/dojo.css";
@import "./res/dojo__1_10_4/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css";
</style>
<style>
```